# Rails 4 Searchkick Suggestions Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

Working on getting a 'did you mean?' functionality integrated with my rails 4 app. I am using searchkick with elasticsearch.

I have finally gotten the did you mean to display when a user misspells a query with this code in the view:

```
<%= @articles.suggestions %>
```

However, when there aren't any suggestions, I get `undefined method 'suggestions'`

Do I need to define suggestions in the controller? I have tried to only display suggestions when they are present using this:

```
<% if @articles.suggestions.present? %>
  <%= @articles.suggestions %>
<% end %>
```

but get the same error. What is the best way to go about this? Still very new to searchkick so I appreciate any help.

Here is my search method in the articles_controller:

```
@articles = Article.search(params[:q], misspellings: {edit_distance: 1}, suggest: true, fields: ["specific^10", "title", "aka", "category", "tags_name", "nutritiontable"], boost_where: {specific: :exact}, page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
```

and article.rb:

```
searchkick  autocomplete: ['specific'], suggest: ['specific'], conversions: "conversions"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try):

```
<%= @articles.try(:suggestions) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting an approach which does not rely on `Object#try`

```
<% if @articles.respond_to?(:suggestions) %>
    <%= @articles.suggestions %>
<% end %>
```